# MSBuild Community Taks RegexReplace remove trailing slash from path

Tags: regex, msbuild, msbuildcommunitytasks

I am trying to use MSBuild community tasks to remove the slash from the end of the OutputPath

This is what i have so far.

```
<RegexReplace Input="$(OutputPath)" Expression="\$" Replacement="" Count="1">
 <Output ItemName="FormattedOutputPath" TaskParameter="Output" />
</RegexReplace>
<Message Text="@(FormattedOutputPath)"/>
```

Unfortunately the message just returns my path still with the slash on the end.
The path is C:\MyDirectory\

It looks like my expression is incorrect

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slash is using as an escape character, so in pattern you have to escape slash character by another slash:

```
<RegexReplace Input="$(OutputPath)" Expression="\\$" Replacement="" Count="1">
  <Output ItemName="FormattedOutputPath" TaskParameter="Output" />
</RegexReplace>
<Message Text="@(FormattedOutputPath)"/>
```

To better understand escaping see the following examples:

1. `$` represents end of line/string
2. `\$` represents dollar sign character
3. `\\` represents slash character
4. `\\$` represents slash character at the end of line/string

Comment: Thanks - i had tested the Expression on a javascript regex tester and it worked but as i was looking at it i was guessing that this might be the case.  Thanks again :)